# Phalcon dev tools install not working

Tags: php, phalcon

I followed this page to install phalcon dev tools.

https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/3.1.0/reference/linuxtools.html

The problem is that when I type $ **phalcon** in the terminal it gives this response:

```
Phalcon DevTools (3.1.2)

#!/usr/bin/env php
PHP Notice:  Constant COMPATIBLE_VERSION already defined in /home/jarno/phalcon-devtools/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 106

Phalcon DevTools (3.1.2)

#!/usr/bin/env php
PHP Notice:  Constant COMPATIBLE_VERSION already defined in /home/jarno/phalcon-devtools/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 106

Phalcon DevTools (3.1.2)

#!/usr/bin/env php
PHP Notice:  Constant COMPATIBLE_VERSION already defined in /home/jarno/phalcon-devtools/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 106

Phalcon DevTools (3.1.2)

#!/usr/bin/env php
PHP Notice:  Constant COMPATIBLE_VERSION already defined in /home/jarno/phalcon-devtools/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 106

Phalcon DevTools (3.1.2)

#!/usr/bin/env php
PHP Notice:  Constant COMPATIBLE_VERSION already defined in /home/jarno/phalcon-devtools/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 106

Phalcon DevTools (3.1.2)

#!/usr/bin/env php
PHP Notice:  Constant COMPATIBLE_VERSION already defined in /home/jarno/phalcon-devtools/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 106

Phalcon DevTools (3.1.2)

#!/usr/bin/env php
PHP Notice:  Constant COMPATIBLE_VERSION already defined in /home/jarno/phalcon-devtools/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 106

Phalcon DevTools (3.1.2)

#!/usr/bin/env php
PHP Notice:  Constant COMPATIBLE_VERSION already defined in /home/jarno/phalcon-devtools/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 106
PHP Fatal error:  Maximum recursion depth exceeded in /home/jarno/phalcon-devtools/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 115
```

Comment: There exists an issue report: https://github.com/phalcon/phalcon-devtools/issues/1006
Have you tried the suggested solution there to checkout branch 3.2.x?

Comment: Thanks man it works!